# How to add data from Combo Box to Table Column using a Button in JavaFX?

Tags: button, javafx, combobox, tableview, tablecolumn

So I have the following code:

```
public class ToDoListController implements Initializable {

    String text = "";
    LocalDate isoDate;

    @FXML
    private Button bttnAddEvent;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker pickerDate;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> eventsSelector;

    @FXML
    private Button bttnDone;

    @FXML
    private Button bttnRemove;

    @FXML
    private TableView<EventsBean> eventsTable;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<EventsBean, String> eventCol;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<EventsBean, LocalDate> dateCol;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> doneCol;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> observationCol;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> removeCol;

    @FXML
    void bttnDoneAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void bttnRemoveAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void pickerDateAction(ActionEvent event) {
         isoDate = pickerDate.getValue();
    }

            ObservableList<EventsBean> dataList = 
    FXCollections.observableArrayList();


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    System.out.println("The pane loaded");

    List<String> myList;
    try {
        myList = Files.lines(Paths.get("src/com/todolist/EventsList.txt")).collect(Collectors.toList());
        eventsSelector.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(myList));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Don t find file");
    }

    eventCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<EventsBean, String>("event"));
    dateCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<EventsBean, LocalDate>("date"));

    observationCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<EventsBean, String>("observation"));
    observationCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<EventsBean>forTableColumn());
    observationCol.setOnEditCommit(
            (CellEditEvent<EventsBean, String> t) -> {
                ((EventsBean) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                    t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                    ).setObservation(t.getNewValue());
        });
    observationCol.setSortable(false);

    eventsTable.setItems(dataList);
    eventsTable.setEditable(true);

    bttnAddEvent.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
        text = eventsSelector.getValue().toString();
        dataList.add(new EventsBean(text, isoDate, ""));
    });

    }
    }
```

and my EventsBean class:

```
public class EventsBean {

private SimpleStringProperty observation;
private SimpleStringProperty event;
private SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate> date;

public EventsBean(String event, LocalDate date, String observation) {
    this.event = new SimpleStringProperty(event);
    this.date = new SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate>(date);      
    this.observation = new SimpleStringProperty(observation);
}
public String getEvent() {
    return event.get();
}

public LocalDate getDate() {
    return date.get();
}
public String getObservation() {
    return observation.get();
}

public void setObservation(String observation) {
    this.observation.set(observation);
}
}
```

As you can see, I populate the `ComboBox` with data from a text file.
So I want to use `Button bttnAddEvent` to add a selected data from `ComboBox` in `TableColumn <?,?> eventCol`. Beside this, another challenge it is to use the same `Button bttnAddEvent` in the same time with data from `ComboBox` to add the selected date from `DatePicker pickerDate` in `TableColumn <?,?> dateCol`.

Update: Until now I put the value of ComboBox into a String named text, but how to transfer into TableColumn  eventCol this value from text?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution and updated the code for someone who will meet this need.